# Custom metric (hmeasure) for summaryFunction caret classification

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

I am trying to use the hmeasure metric [Hand,2009](http://www.hmeasure.net) as my custom metric for training SVMs in caret. As I am relatively new to using R, I tried adapt the twoClassSummary function. All I need is to pass the true class labels and predicted class probability from the model (an svm) to the HMeasure function from the *hmeasure* package instead of using ROC or other measures of classification performance in caret.

For example, a call to the HMeasure function in R - HMeasure(true.class,predictedProbs[,2])- results in calculation of the Hmeasure. Using an adaptation of twoClassSummary code below results in an error being returned: 'x' must be numeric.

Maybe that train function can't "see" the predicted probabilities to evaluate the HMeasure function. How can I fix this?

I ve read the documentation, and linked questions posed on SO [dealing with regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065237/r-caret-model-evaluation-with-alternate-performance-metric). Thats got me some of the way. I would be grateful for any help or pointers towards a solution.

```
library(caret)
library(doMC)
library(hmeasure)
library(mlbench)

set.seed(825)

data(Sonar)
table(Sonar$Class) 
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[inTraining, ]
testing <- Sonar[-inTraining, ]


# using caret
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 2,repeats=2,summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,classProbs=TRUE)

svmFit1 <- train(Class ~ ., data = training,method = "svmRadial",trControl =    fitControl,preProc = c("center", "scale"),tuneLength = 8,metric = "ROC")

predictedProbs <- predict(svmFit1, newdata = testing , type = "prob")
true.class<-testing$Class
hmeas<- HMeasure(true.class,predictedProbs[,2]) # suppose its Rocks we're interested in predicting
hmeasure.probs<-hmeas$metrics[c('H')] # returns the H measure metric 

hmeasureCaret<-function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL,...) 
{ 
# adaptation of twoClassSummary
require(hmeasure)
if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == levels(data[, "obs"]))) 
 stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")
#lev is a character string that has the outcome factor levels taken from the training   data
hObject <- try(hmeasure::HMeasure(data$obs, data[, lev[1]]),silent=TRUE)
hmeasH <- if (class(hObject)[1] == "try-error") {
NA
} else {hObject$metrics[[1]]  #hObject$metrics[c('H')] returns a dataframe, need to    return a vector 
}
out<-hmeasH 
names(out) <- c("Hmeas")
#class(out)
}
environment(hmeasureCaret) <- asNamespace('caret')
```

Non working code below.

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", summaryFunction = hmeasureCaret,classProbs=TRUE,allowParallel = TRUE,
                  verboseIter=TRUE,returnData=FALSE,savePredictions=FALSE)
set.seed(1)

svmTune <- train(Class.f ~ ., data = training,method = "svmRadial",trControl =    ctrl,preProc = c("center", "scale"),tuneLength = 8,metric="Hmeas",
              verbose = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code works. I m posting a solution in case anyone else wants to use/improve upon this.
The problems were caused by incorrect referencing of the Hmeasure object and a typo/comment on the returned value of the function.

```
library(caret)
library(doMC)
library(hmeasure)
library(mlbench)

set.seed(825)
registerDoMC(cores = 4)

data(Sonar)
table(Sonar$Class) 

inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[inTraining, ]
testing <- Sonar[-inTraining, ]

hmeasureCaret<-function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL,...) 
{ 
  # adaptation of twoClassSummary
  require(hmeasure)
  if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == levels(data[, "obs"]))) 
    stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")
  hObject <- try(hmeasure::HMeasure(data$obs, data[, lev[1]]),silent=TRUE)
  hmeasH <- if (class(hObject)[1] == "try-error") {
    NA
  } else {hObject$metrics[[1]]  #hObject$metrics[c('H')] returns a dataframe, need to return a vector 
  }
  out<-hmeasH 
  names(out) <- c("Hmeas")
  out 
}
#environment(hmeasureCaret) <- asNamespace('caret')


ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 10, repeats = 5, summaryFunction = hmeasureCaret,classProbs=TRUE,allowParallel = TRUE,
                     verboseIter=FALSE,returnData=FALSE,savePredictions=FALSE)
set.seed(123)

svmTune <- train(Class ~ ., data = training,method = "svmRadial",trControl = ctrl,preProc = c("center", "scale"),tuneLength = 15,metric="Hmeas",
                 verbose = FALSE)
svmTune

predictedProbs <- predict(svmTune, newdata = testing , type = "prob")

true.class<-testing$Class

hmeas.check<- HMeasure(true.class,predictedProbs[,2])

summary(hmeas.check)
```

Comment: not sure what the etiquette is on accepting your own answer. Can someone let me know?

Comment: If the answer helped you it's OK, don't worry.